# Unable to remove embedded object from array in Spring Boot MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a collection "users", in which contains field **"carts"** which is array of object. Something like this

```
{
_id: '61249cb6709f5f61ec6d8372',
name: 'ABC',
carts: [
    {
        cartId: 'cartId-1",
        name: 'test'
    },
    {
        cartId: 'cartId-2",
        name: 'test2'
    }
]
```

Now I want to remove Object containing **"cartId":'cartId-1'**.
I have tried this -

```
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(
            Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is("61249cb6709f5f61ec6d8372")),
            new Update().pull("carts", new BasicDBObject("cartId", "cartId-1")),
            Users.class
    );
```

But it still doesn't remove the embedded object from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code by passing objectid instead of string.

Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId("61249cb6709f5f61ec6d8372"")))